# Macedonia- visa on arrival for Indians holding US multiple entry visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, paperwork, macedonia

Indian - is it posssible to get a visa for a week with my US multiple visa ?

Comment: Why do you think holding a US visa helps you with a Maceconian visa? Would it work the other way round?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MK&selDest=Macedonia%20%28FYROM%29&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a visa issued by
>   Canada, **USA** or United Kingdom. The visa must be valid for at
>   least 5 days beyond the period of intended stay in Macedonia
>   (FYROM). They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 15 days per visit, and 90 days within 180 days.

So Indians with a valid US visa do **not** need a visa for Macedonia.

Answer (score 0):

No, Indians holding Indian Passport do require a VISA to enter Macedonia (FYROM).

If one has a multiple entry Schengen VISA then they can stay up to a maximum of 15 consecutive days in FYROM.

Comment: Indeed, there's been a Change since my answer was posted. Will update